# Exit javascript function when same function is called again

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my website I first call a javascript function that enables users to change the layout of a specific element on my website. Then when a user changes the value of a dropdown, the same javascript function is called but then the user should change the layout of the new element he choose.

The problem is that the first function stays alive so they both keep execution. This means that the user then changes the layout of the first element and the second one (when only the second should be changed)

Code extract:

```
//Called function in page load
general_layout_changes(chart_variables);

//Called function when dropbox value changes
$(document).on('change', '.report_item_choosen', function(){
    general_layout_changes(chart_variables);
});

//Part of the function
function general_layout_changes(chart_variables){
        $(document).on('keyup', '.change-text-x-label', function() {
            var changeText = $( this ).val();
            var svg = d3.select("#" + chart_variables.chart_id_name + "_content").transition();

            svg.select("text.x-label")  
                .text(changeText);  
        });
}
```

Comment: if you have some code, we can [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: _the first function stays alive_ what?

Comment: Sounds like you have a recursive function. Can you post some code for us to see?

Comment: Sorry posted to soon, I added a small code extract

Comment: code will ad a new `keyup` handler every time `.report_item_choosen` is changed causing multiple conflicting event handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding **multiple times** the **same event listener** on the **same element**: on each call of your `general_layout_changes` function, you bind **another** event listener.

You could replace the whole code presented by this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.change-text-x-label', function() {
    var changeText = $( this ).val();
    var svg = d3.select("#" + chart_variables.chart_id_name + "_content").transition();
    svg.select("text.x-label").text(changeText);
});
```

This will do the same, but better, in that it will bind the event only once.